# Can't call column names in a dataframe after GROUPBY

Tags: python, group-by

Sorry about the formatting.  Can't seem to figure that out.

Unable to refer to column names in a grouped dataframe.

```
dfbidFeed       

MARKET  30D_PCLICK      
Dallas       5      
Dallas       4      
Houston     10      
Houston     13      
New York     7      
New York    12      
St. Louis   15      
St. Louis   14
```

Then I run this code to compute the mean and the sum of `CLICKS`, grouped by `MARKET`

```
dfclicks_grouped = dfbidFeed['30D_PCLICK']
                   .groupby([dfbidFeed['MARKET']])
                   .agg({"returns": [np.mean, np.sum]})
```

returns:

```
MARKET       mean   sum     
Dallas       4.5     9  
Houston     11.5    23  
New York     9.5    19  
St. Louis   14.5    29
```

I want to be able to merge `dfclicks_grouped` with another `df`.  However, I can't seem to refer to the columns in `dfclicks_grouped`.
It doesn't behave like a dataframe where I can refer to the column name and get a result.  (i.e. `dfbidFeed['MARKET']` returns the list of markets.

When I do this (`dfclicks_grouped['MARKET']`, I get:  `keyError:  'MARKET'`

How do I make the colunn names in `dfclicks_grouped` callable?

Comment: In your `groupby` statement set this option `as_index` to `False`.

Comment: I get this message:     TypeError: as_index=False only valid with DataFrame.   Here is my code:     dfclicks_grouped = dfbidFeed['30D_PCLICK'].groupby([dfbidFeed['MARKET']] ,as_index=False).agg({"returns": [np.mean, np.sum]})

Comment: `dfbidFeed['30D_PCLICK']` is probably a `Series` and that option only works with `DataFrames`